# Python TypeError using the translate() method

Tags: python, unicode, typeerror

I am trying to build a function in Python that pulls specific characters out of a string, and then returns each of the remaining words on a separate line. Apostrophes must be removed -- and the contraction must be split, with the second half moving to a new line.

For instance, I have this sentence fragment:

> ", that doesn't mean much to him."

And I want to remove these punctuation characters:

> ",'."

It should return:

```
that
doesn
t
mean
much
to
him
```

Here is the function I've written:

```
def remove_chars(frag, punc):
    if "'" in frag:
        frag = frag.replace("'", " ")

    frag = frag.translate(None, punc)

    frag = frag.split(" ")

    for i in frag:
        print i

remove_chars(", that doesn't mean much to him.", ",'.")
```

And here's the error I'm receiving:

> TypeError: deletions are implemented differently for unicode

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a whole lot more research, and I finally came up with this -- which I think is correct (and probably the cleanest solution):

```
def remove_chars(frag, punc):

    for i in punc:
        frag = frag.replace(i, ' ')
    for j in frag.split():
        print j


print remove_chars(", that doesn't mean much to him.", ",'.")
```

If you see a mistake, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The `unicode.translate()` method is indeed different from the `str.translate()` method. It takes just **one** argument, a dictionary mapping integer codepoint values to other values. To delete, that other value should be `None`.

You can trivially create such a dictionary using [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
mapping = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, punc))
frag = frag.translate(mapping)
```

Since the keys must be integers, I used `ord` to map each character in the string `punc` to the corresponding integer codepoint. `dict.fromkeys()` then creates a dictionary with all those integer keys and gives each of them the default value `None`.

Demo:

```
>>> punc = ",'."
>>> dict.fromkeys(map(ord, punc))
{44: None, 46: None, 39: None}
>>> mapping = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, punc))
>>> u", that doesn't mean much to him.".translate(mapping)
u' that doesnt mean much to him'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, this `deletions are implemented differently for unicode` has come in my code with the following specs:

- Python 2
- Use `from __future__ import unicode literals`
- String to be transtated is str or bytes
- Translate function written like `mystr.translate(None, ',-()')`

The problem here is the string `' ,-()'` that because of the `unicode_literals` import, it is unicode. The solution it to write it like:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

' Any-cleaned string(seriously), string'.translate(None, b',-()')
```